# Unable to perform 'maxBy' on a Flink windowed stream of type <SampleClass> by using the SampleClass's field as a parameter does not work

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

Lets say this is my sample stream like so:

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, SampleClass>> sampleStream = previousStream
                                    .keyBy(value -> value.f1.getId())
                                    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
```

`SampleClass` has two fields `id` and `time`. It also has two getter methods `getId()` and `getTime` that gets those respective fields.

Goal: Now I want to perform the `maxBy` operation on the above stream with the `time` as my condition for maximiziation. Basically, I want the latest element in the front of the window.

How do I achieve my goal?

`maxBy` works on position of parameter and not on nested field inside it. For example:

```
.maxBy(positionToMaxBy = 1, first = true)
```

Here `positionToMaxBy` would consider the second parameter from the stream parameters, which is the object. But how do I get it to use the `getTime()` method to be used instead of the whole object?

Comment: From what you've shared, it looks like using a Tuple2 is just getting in the way. At least in this sample code, the String field in the Tuple isn't used, so why not just use a `DataStream<SampleClass>` instead?

Comment: Hey @DavidAnderson. Unfortunately, there is a lot of stream processing happening before this step. This is why the stream has to be in this format.

Answer (score 0):

A few solutions:

- use a map before applying the windowing that transforms `Tuple2<String, SampleClass>` to `SampleClass`
- or if you need the String, add it to SampleClass
- use `reduce` instead of `maxBy`
- implement `Comparable` on `SampleClass` and have the `compareTo` method only check the time field

Comment: The first two points make sense. But I require maxBy because I need the latest event at the top of the window. How can I achieve this using reduce?